# Can't set component width in picker view

Tags: ios, xcode

Am trying to set the width of two components in a picker view. They are of equal width, and I want to make one wider. For this reason, I have used the

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component

method.

My problem is that after I have set the method, I only get one component back instead of two. I have checked to see if I have written the method wrong, but can't find anything wrong.

Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#import "BIDDependentComponentPickerViewController.h"

@implementation BIDDependentComponentPickerViewController

@synthesize picker;
@synthesize stateZips;
@synthesize states;
@synthesize zips;


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger stateRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kStateComponent];
    NSInteger zipRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kZipComponent];

    NSString *state = [self.states objectAtIndex:stateRow];
    NSString *zip = [self.zips objectAtIndex:zipRow];

    NSString *title= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected zip code %@.", zip];
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"@% is in @%", zip, state];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                    message:message 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *plistURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"statedictionary" withExtension:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];
    self.stateZips = dictionary;

    NSArray *components = [self.stateZips allKeys];
    NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.states = sorted;

    NSString *selectedState = [self.states objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [stateZips objectForKey:selectedState];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.picker = nil;
    self.stateZips = nil;
    self.states = nil;
    self.zips = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == kStateComponent) {
        return [self.states count];
        return [self.zips count];
    }
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == kStateComponent)
        return [self.states objectAtIndex:row];
    return [self.zips objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (component == kStateComponent)
    {
    NSString *selectedState = [self.states objectAtIndex:row];
    NSArray *array = [stateZips objectForKey:selectedState];

    self.zips = array;
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kZipComponent animated:YES];
    [picker reloadComponent:kZipComponent];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == kZipComponent) {
        return 90;
        return 200;
    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
return 200;
```

is never reached. It should be outside the IF statement like so:

```
if (component == kZipComponent) {
    return 90.0;
}
return 200.0;
```

Otherwise, your method does not return a value for any component OTHER than kZipComponent (so the width of other components is 0).

Comment: Thank you. Made the change but when I tried to run it, Xcode crashed with this message: Couldn't register Apress.Pickers with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) Then quit Xcode and restarted it, but crashed again. Any idea what to do? TIA

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue altogether. If you're running the app in the simulator, make sure the running instance is closed before rebuilding (maybe close the simulator altogether). If that doesn't work, you may want to open the issue as a new question.

Comment: You're right, it is a completely separate issue. I will do some debugging and see if I can resolve the issue. Thanks again.